# highstock graph with month only records

Tags: date, highcharts

I try to do something that should be super easy, I try to draw a chart with monthly data. I just whant to show the last 12 or 24 month in the past with it's data. I get the data from a MSSQL server so I can twist the date to meet highstock format (I tried the number of second from 1/1/1970 with no success).

```
   data='[';
   <cfloop query="maquery">
    data = data + '#mois_annee#, #nb#,';
   </cfloop>
   data = data.slice(0, -1);
       data = data + ']';
       $(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'div_graph',
            width : 600,
            height : 300
        },
        series : [{
            type : 'column',
            name : 'Acheteurs Uniques',
            data : eval(data),
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }],
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });
});
```

way simplier to explain with JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=PIqVEj8qnp

Comment: Supported format for dates in Highcharts is only timestamp in milliseconds. See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) - Example 2b).

Comment: Thanks to point this out, fallowing this sample I managed it to work ! Thanks !